# Define a square matrix with np.ogrid and ascending exponents

Tags: python, numpy

I want to define the Matrix $V_{0} = (c_{i}^{j - 1})$, for $i, j \in {1,…,s}$

So the first column of this matrix would be (0,0,…,0), the second one (c_{1}, c_{2},…, c_{s}) and the last column ((c_{1})^{s}, (c_{2})^{s},…, (c_{s})^{s}).

I have defined the vector $c$ beforehand. Which means that if c has s elements, our matrix V has s arrays and columns respectively.

I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
import random
s = 4
c = np.array([random.randint(1,10)]*(s))
print(c)
m = 4
n = 4 
i,j = np.ogrid[:m,:n]
V = c[i]*(j-1)
print(V)
```

And then I received this:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-f744ca90252c> in <cell line: 9>()
      7 n = 4
      8 i,j = np.ogrid[:m,:n]
----> 9 V = c[i+1]*j
     10 print(V)

IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4
```

Which I don’t understand, because I ensured that $c$ has $s$ elements and that m=n=s. (m and s are the amount of arrays/columns)

What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: Note that all indexing in Python (and NumPy) is zero based. Valid indices into an array or a list of size 4 are 0,1,2,3 but not 4.

Comment: Are you looking to make a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)? If so, then you might be able to use [`np.vander`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vander.html)